# Quarkus: custom SecurityIdentity

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, rbac

In a quarkus app, I'd like to develop my own SecurityIdentity, because existing ones do not fit my need (I need to check identity by getting roles from multiple micro-services). Maybe a custom SecurityIdentity is not the best option, but looking at documentation it seems to be what I need (another option is to define a ContainerRequestFilter implementation but this is at lower level and less integrated).

Is there any way to do it? I tested the following:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
class CustomSecurityIdentity: SecurityIdentity {
   override fun getPrincipal(): Principal {
     ....
```

Then from an endpoint I simply defined:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@RolesAllowed("administrator")
@Path("/")
fun checkAuth(): Response {
  ...
```

I put some breakpoints everywhere but it never comes through my Identity Provider where the @RolesAllowed should (the way I see it) force it.

Is it possible to make it work?

Comment: I believe your use case, that is, getting roles from multiple external sources and adding them to the identity, can be achieved by implementing a `SecurityIdentityAugmentor`, as documented here: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-customization#security-identity-customization

Comment: I tried this also, however it was never used. Somewhere else I tried to inject a SecurityIdentity bean, but quarkus couldn't find any; so I think that in the basic configuration there is no SecurityIdentity defined, so a SecurityIdentityAugmentor is useless.

Comment: I see, so you don't have a `SecurityIdentity` at all. My understanding from your question was that you "only" want to get roles from external sources. The question is, do you need to fetch the whole identity from external source(s), or would some built-in security provider be enough for you and you'd just need to get the roles? You can probably start here: https://quarkus.io/guides/security#identity-providers

Comment: @Ladicek as I understand the link you provided, it explains how to use existing Identity Providers but not how to build a custom one. It would be great to have some quarkus documentation about how the extension do it.